# TYPO3 10.4: Is it possible to get the built-in filebrowser in a custom backend module/frontend plugin?

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

I have a backend module for my extension which allows the user to upload images to certain records.

So far so good. But just uploading images from the desktop is not enough.

[image: I want to use the filebrowser from Typo3.]

I've already searched on the internet, the TYPO3 API and it's extensions but couldn't find anything helpfull.

Comment: We wanted to implement this a while back for `cs-seo`, but research made us conclude that we had to rebuild the whole TCA Context to make it work outside of the tt_content Context.

To conclude, there is no "TYPO3-Way" doing so. 

Most developers work around this by linking to specific tt_content records in their Backend Modules, which will in turn handle core functionality like File Upload.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, sorry - the API is not meant to be used in the FE

Comment: Okay but what about the backend?